# How can I get the Campaign IDs of Leads through triggers?

Tags: trigger, leads, campaign, campaign-member

I have tried this. Not working. (CampaignIds is a set)

```
for (Lead lead : Trigger.new) {
    CampaignIds.add(lead.CampaignId);
}
```

Comment: can you post your whole code, and explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: The other codes are not relevant. I am trying to save the lead's campaign IDs in a set. But for some reasons lead.CampaignId cannot get that. @MarcZaharescu

Comment: How you can say that other codes are not relevant if this is the case then only you can solve this problem we can't help you;

Comment: Somebody has helped without the other codes. @itzmukeshy7

Comment: @DIPXOID That is great!!!

Comment: feel free to mark the answer that helped you as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [SELECT Id, CampaignId, LeadId FROM CampaignMember WHERE LeadId IN :leadsInTrigger ]

Using this query you get all campaign member for the leads that are in your trigger scope. From that you should be able to determine for which campaigns each lead is a member.

Answer (score 3):

As per the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000205967&language=en_US), the Campaign field on the Lead object is not accessible via the API. So you will have to do this via the Campaign Member object, which associates leads and campaigns together.

Code from [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008xZbIAI) may be helpful.